# MySQL -> create alias for DATE_FORMAT function with given pattern

Tags: mysql

I just wanted to know if it was possible to do something like:

```
CREATE ALIAS SOLR_DATE_FORMAT FOR DATE_FORMAT(date_val,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')
```

`DATE_FORMAT(date_val,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')` exists in MySQL, but I'd like to give it another name and make it a one argument function, because in my unit tests I use another DB (H2) on which I defined such a `SOLR_DATE_FORMAT` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your [own function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function.html):

```
DELIMITER $$
create function SOLR_DATE_FORMAT( date_val ) 
returns char(20)
begin
   return DATE_FORMAT(date_val,'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ');
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDITED** Fixed returned type. Thanks eggyal!